# Gulp less combine several files, let others separate

Tags: gulp, less

Say I have

```
main1.less
main2.less
main3.less
other1.less
other2.less
other3.less
```

I need the output

```
main.css
other1.css
other2.css
other3.css
```

I do

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./Content/css/**/*.less'])
        .pipe(less({
            paths: [path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes')]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + 'css'));
});
```

Actually it generates a css for a less file... Is there a way to combine several files in one, and let others in separate files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) to combine the styles you want into one file from a separate task.

```js
const gulp   = require('gulp4');
const less   = require('gulp-less');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const path   = require('path');
const config = {
  paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
};

gulp.task('less:separate', () => gulp
  .src(path.join(__dirname, 'Content', 'css', '**', 'other*.less'))
  .pipe(less(config))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + 'css')));

gulp.task('less:together', () => gulp
  .src(path.join(__dirname, 'Content', 'css', '**', 'main*.less'))
  .pipe(less(config))
  .pipe(concat('main.css')) // combine them into one file
  .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + 'css')));

gulp.task('less', gulp.parallel('less:separate', 'less:together'));
```